# Godot listening to signals from multiple instances of the same scene

Tags: godot

I have the following Scenes:
Player
Enemy
Attack

When an Attack collides with the Enemy, the Enemy emits a "onHit" signal.

The Player listens for that signal and bounces back.

This is all working good, but now if I duplicate the enemy so there are multiple Enemy scenes, how do I listen to the signal on all of them? Is there a way to grab all instances of a Scene and connect to all of their signals? Is there a better way of sending this message back to the Player?

I'm very new to Godot so any advice is very helpful! Thanks.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use a Signal Bus.

*Yes, you could iterate over the nodes and find all the enemies (e.g. by comparing their script). However, it is easier if all the enemies register themselves to a list (or a group) on `_ready`. However, you don't need any of that.*

The insight is this: An object can emit signals of other objects.

We take advantage of that by creating a Signal Bus. Which is a a common pattern in Godot. It goes as follows:

- Create an [autoload (singleton)](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/step_by_step/singletons_autoload.html) script. *Let us call it `SignalBus`*.
- In the script, define signals. And nothing else. *In our case, we define `on_hit`:

  ```
  signal on_hit
  ```
- Every place that needs to emit a signal does it from the signal bus. *In this case the enemies do this:*

  *Godot 3 or Godot 4*

  ```
  SignalBus.emit_signal("on_hit")
  ```

  *Or using the new Godot 4 syntax:*

  ```
  SignalBus.on_hit.emit()
  ```
- And where you need to handle the signal, connect to it. For example on `_ready`. *Something like this:*

  *Godot 3*

  ```
  func _ready() -> void:
      SignalBus.connect("on_hit", self, "_on_hit")

  func _on_hit() -> void:
      # whatever
      pass
  ```

  *Godot 4 legacy syntax (this syntax eases upgrading code)*

  ```
  func _ready() -> void:
      SignalBus.connect("on_hit", Callable(self, "_on_hit"))

  func _on_hit() -> void:
      # whatever
      pass
  ```

  *In Godot 4 we can simply pass a method reference as a `Callable`:*

  ```
  func _ready() -> void:
      SignalBus.connect("on_hit", _on_hit)

  func _on_hit() -> void:
      # whatever
      pass
  ```

  *Or using the new Godot 4 syntax:*

  ```
  func _ready() -> void:
      SignalBus.on_hit.connect(_on_hit)

  func _on_hit() -> void:
      # whatever
      pass
  ```

This way the emitters and receivers of a signal don't need to know each other. They only need to know the Signal Bus. Which is available everywhere (by virtue of being an autoload).

Comment: This solution worked beautifully! Thank you very much for your time explaining it!

Comment: Doesn't that add a layer of indirection? Suppose I need to react to a button being pressed somewhere else. Instead of attaching the handler directly to the button we now call SignalBus.emit... which will in turn call our handler. I'm a noob, just wondering if sticking to this strategy might cause performance issues down the road.

Comment: @Atmaks Correct. This adds a layer of indirection. So both parts are fully decoupled. Without it you need to reach one object from the other to be able to connect them, which be error prone and hard to maintain. Imagine, for example, every blue switch must open every blue door, and the same for other colors. As you build your scenario, you need to remember to make all the connections in the designer... You might forget, it might be hard to track when a connection is wrong. Imagine the same, but doors and switches are buried in layers of scenes, and the scenario is procedural... You get it.

Comment: @Theraot Yes, I get that, but I was wandering specifically about possible performance impact. Well, I suppose one should write in C++ from the start if things like this impact performance meaningfully, right?

Comment: @Atmaks No. Optimization is not simply doing the dumb approach faster. There is value in writing GDScript first: you iterate the design faster, and you can find the performance bottlenecks by profiling. Then, if and where the performance is bad... First: find a way to accomplish the same by doing less (remove overhead, work with Servers instead of Nodes). Second: Find a way to accomplish the same by doing less often (caches, memoization, baking). Third: Find a way to accomplish the same by doing faster (port to C#, or C++, or similar). And chances are that the SignalBus is not your bottleneck.

Comment: @Theraot Signal connecting syntax has been changed in Godot 4, so instead of 
SignalBus.connect("on_hit", self, "_on_hit") it would be SignalBus.on_hit.connect(_on_hit)

https://github.com/godotengine/godot-docs/issues/5577

Comment: @CaseyKeller The old syntax still works, which is good for cases where the signal is not known until runtime (which, I'd admit is rare). I've added the new syntax to the answer.

Comment: huh, i'm on v4.1.1 and both syntax's work for emitting, but i can only get the new one to work for connecting; using the old one i get an error like "Invalid argument for "connect()" function: argument 2 should be Callable but is res://Sprite2D.gd.
Invalid argument for "connect()" function: argument 3 should be Array but is String."

Comment: @CaseyKeller Ah, yes, I entire forgot about that. I'll fix the answer. Edit: done.