# Is there such thing as a global variable? (GDscript)

Tags: variables, global-variables, gdscript

I'm trying to make a game but I need something like a global variable for it to work. Is there a way in GDscript that you can make a variable that works across all nodes with scripts. I need a button that makes you buy a gun which would set a variable to true and with that variable being true, you could equip the gun.

This question doesn't really fit this section where it says: What did you try and what were you expecting? so I'm just gonna skip it.

Answer (score 3):

---

### New Answer

Starting with Godot 4.1 you can use static variables:

```
static var my_variable := true
```

All the instances of your script will share these variables.

Also you can make the equivalent of the `Globals` autoload by using a `class_name` like this:

```
class_name Globals

static var has_gun := false
```

Which you do not need to register as an autoload. You just need to have this script somewhere in your project.

Godot has also static methods (`static func`), which you can call from anywhere.

Be aware that this approach makes for an inconvinient [signal bus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68675270/402022), because currently there are no static signals ([proposal](https://github.com/godotengine/godot-proposals/issues/6851)). But there are workarounds, see: [How to write a static event emitter in GDScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77026952/402022).

---

### Old Answer

> Is there a way in GDscript that you can make a variable that works across all nodes with scripts.

You could use an [autoload](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/scripting/singletons_autoload.html).

Go to the Project menu, the Project Settings option, in the Autoloads tab… And there you can set a script, and give it a name. It will be available for every node in the scene tree.

For example, you can have a "globals.gd" script that looks like this:

```
extends Node

var has_gun := false
```

Then you make it an autoload with the name "Globals". So in any other script you can use it. For example:

```
extends Node

func _ready() -> void:
    print(Globals.has_gun)
```

*And yes, autoloads will stay there even if you change the current scene.*

*You might also be interested in the Signal bus (Event bus) pattern, which involves defining signals in an autoload, such that other scripts emit them or connect to them.*

---

Technically the autoload is not a true global. As I said, the autoload will be available for the nodes in the scene tree.

This also means the autoload will not be available for a script that is not a `Node` (e.g. a `Resource`), or otherwise not in the scene tree.

*Unless you use a hacky workaround to get a reference to the autoload, which I will not go into.*

---

Instead, I will give you an alternative: resource based communication.

This time you create a "global_resource.gd" that look like this:

```
class_name GlobalResource
extends Resource

var has_gun := false
```

And then you can use the context menu on the FileSystem panel to create a new resource. When Godot asks you for the type, you select `GlobalResource`, and give it a name such as "globals.tres".

Then you can use it like this:

```
extends Node

const Globals := preload("res://globals.tres")

func _ready() -> void:
    print(Globals.has_gun)
```

Everywhere you `preload` that same resource file ("globals.tres") you will get the same `Resource` instance. It does not matter if it is in the same scene, or if you changed the current scene.

*And yes, this does not depend on the scene tree. And yes, you can put signals in there too.*

---

For completeness sake, I'll also mention that there is another hacky workaround which involves defining a `Dictionary` or `Array` as `const` in a script with a class name. Since in Godot 3 `const` does not imply inmutable (don't count on this on Godot 4). That is how some people currently work around the lack of static variables. However, I believe you won't find it necessary.

---

**Addendum**: You add custom properties in project -> Project Settings…  And you can give its default value there (even a different one per target platform). In runtime you can read them with `ProjectSettings.get_setting` or write them with `ProjectSettings.set_setting`.