# How to write a static event emitter in GDScript?

Tags: godot, gdscript, godot4

Godot doesn't support static signals, so I tried two approaches:

**Empty `Signal`:**

```
static var my_signal: Signal = Signal()
```

**Custom type:**

```
static var my_signal: StaticSignal = StaticSignal.new()

class_name StaticSignal

var _callables: Dictionary

func connect(callable: Callable) -> void:
    self._callables[callable] = true

func disconnect(callable: Callable) -> void:
    self._callables.erase(callable)

func emit(data: Variant) -> void:
    for callable in self._callables:
        callable(data)
```

The problem is when it comes to `.connect`ing to the signal. With `StaticSignal` I am getting a `.connect` member not found error. With `Signal` I am getting an ignored runtime error.

```
static func _static_init():
    ChatLog.new_message.connect(func(msg):
        if len(_log) >= LIMIT:
            _log.remove_at(0)
        _log.append(msg))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will show two approaches: one on how to create *static* signals and the other on arguably the "expected" approach.

#### Static Signals

Godot doesn't support the keywords to define a static signal. However, we know that when we `load()` or `preload()` some gdscript we get a container resource object of type `GDScript`. A gdscript with a `class_name` is symbolically bound to a `GDScript`.

The gdscript parser has a sort of special treatment of these symbols. We can bypass that. Since the the symbol is actually backed by a `GDScript` object we can cast it to `GDScript` or an ancestor. Then we can add our *static* signals to the `GDScript` resource that the class name is bound to.

Additionally, Godot 4 handles circular dependencies with `class_name`s so this pattern actually possible.

The script with static signals:

```gdscript
extends Node
class_name StaticSignalsClass

static var static_signal_1: Signal = (func():
    # We have to manually add a user signal.
    (StaticSignalsClass as Object).add_user_signal("static_signal_1")
    # Now return a reference to the signal we just defined.
    return Signal(StaticSignalsClass, "static_signal_1")
).call()

# We can also define a helper static method:
static func make_signal(p_obj, p_signal_name: StringName) -> Signal:
    # We use GDScript's duck typing to avoid having to cast p_obj.
    p_obj.add_user_signal(p_signal_name)
    return Signal(p_obj, p_signal_name)

static var static_signal_2: Signal = make_signal(StaticSignalsClass, "static_signal_2")
```

The client script:

```gdscript
static func _static_init():
    StaticSignalsClass.static_signal_1.connect(func(): print("Hello, ss1."))
    StaticSignalsClass.static_signal_2.connect(func(): print("Hello, ss2."))

# Somewhere else...
func emit_stuff():
    StaticSignalsClass.static_signal_1.emit()
    StaticSignalsClass.static_signal_2.emit()
```

#### "Expected" Signal Center

We define an autoload that is the center for our signals. You can create namespaces by

1. Adding a property that holds a script with more signals.
2. Follow the `RenderingServer` pattern with the namespace in the name.

The caveat is to be mindful of the order autoloads are loaded. If an earlier initialized autoload accesses `SignalCenter` it will fail. (However, on `_ready` will work.)

```gdscript
extends Node
# autoload name: SignalCenter

signal chatlog_new_message(msg: String)
signal chatlog_user_joined(guest_id: int)
signal chatlog_user_left(guest_id: int)

# Or

var chatlog := ChatLogSignalCenter.new()

### ChatLogSignalCenter script

extends Object

signal new_message(msg: String)
signal user_joined(guest_id: int)
signal user_left(guest_id: int)
```

The client script:

```gdscript
extends Node
class_name StaticClient

static func _static_init():
    SignalCenter.chatlog_new_message.connect(func(): print(msg))

    # or

    SignalCenter.chatlog.new_message.connect(func(): print(msg))
```