# How to make water that spreads in a turn based grid puzzle godot 2d

Tags: arrays, parent-child, game-development, gdscript, godot4

I'm making a grid based 2d puzzle game where you move each character once, and then end your turn. When your turn ends, water spreads to all surounding free grids next to the current water blocks. If water enters an area inhabited by a character, the character drowns. I can get the water to spread the first round, but the created water blocks don't continue to spread

```
extends Area2D

signal next_turn

@onready var check_up = $CollisionShape2D/ray_up
@onready var check_down = $CollisionShape2D/ray_down
@onready var check_left = $CollisionShape2D/ray_left
@onready var check_right = $CollisionShape2D/ray_right

var water_block = ["res://water.tscn", ]
var water_block_count = 1

# Called when the node enters the scene tree for the first time.
func _ready():
    pass # Replace with function body.


# Called every frame. 'delta' is the elapsed time since the previous frame.
func _process(delta):
    pass


func _on_hud_end_turn():
    var count = 0
    var new_water = 0
    while count != water_block_count:
        var water_scene = load(water_block[count])
        if check_up && check_down && check_left && check_right:
            water_block.remove_at(count)
            new_water -= 1
        if not check_up.is_colliding():
            var water = water_scene.instantiate()
            water.position += Vector2(0, -64)
            add_child(water)
            count += 1
            new_water += 1
            water_block[count] = get_node(water)
        if not check_down.is_colliding():
            var water = water_scene.instantiate()
            water.position += Vector2(0, 64)
            add_child(water)
            count += 1
            new_water += 1
            water_block[count] = get_node(water)
        if not check_left.is_colliding():
            var water = water_scene.instantiate()
            water.position += Vector2(-64, 0)
            add_child(water)
            count += 1
            new_water += 1
            water_block[count] = get_node(water)
        if not check_right.is_colliding():
            var water = water_scene.instantiate()
            water.position += Vector2(64, 0)
            add_child(water)
            count += 1
            new_water += 1
            water_block[count] = get_node(water)
        
    water_block_count += new_water
    next_turn.emit()
```

This is my current code block... it isnt working at all. I first tried to have my water be a packed scene in inself. This allowed me to instantiate the new water blocks being created. The problem was it would only check from the packed scene. This was my attempt to fix that by saving the water child node created into an array so i could call that array to create spread at that node. I also added a part in the beginning to delete nodes that are no long spreading from the array. I get "Invalid type in function 'get_node' in base 'Area2D (Water.gd)'. Cannot convert argument 1 from Object to NodePath"

Comment: I suspect the script you are showing is attached to the scene at `res://water.tscn`, is that corect? Also, can you tell how `_on_hud_end_turn` is connected?

Comment: that is correct i put the script on the water scene. also i use a signal to activate '_on_hud_end_turn'. when a player presses the end turn button, it allows the water to spread to the nearest open tiles. then the player can move characters again.\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Errors in the code

*I'll go over this quickly, as I believe the design is wrong, and so fixing the errors will not result in the correct behavior.*

We will begin by looking at this code:

```
water_block[count] = get_node(water)
```

First, the method `get_node` takes a `NodePath` return a `Node` or fails. In your code it is failing, because you are passing `water` to `get_node`... And `water` is set to the result of `instantiate`, which means that `water` is already a `Node`. Making the call to `get_node` pointless.

Second, you have a `water_block` defined as an `Array` containing a `String` (a scene path). The code expects `water_block` to contain scene paths, since you call `load` on its members. Meaning that if you add a `Node` to it (either `water` or the result from `get_node`) then `load` will fail. In fact, the only relevant scene path is `"res://water.tscn"` so you do not need an array for them at all.

Third, if you are always loading the same scene, ideally you would preload it:

```
const water_scene = preload("res://water.tscn")
```

But since the script at hand is attached to that scene, we have a scene that depends on itself. And that makes me question the design. The issues being that:

- Every instance has a list of instances.
- They all make new instances their children.
- Only the first instance is connected to the end of the turn signal (the newly created instances are not being connected in the code, and the call is not propagated to them either).
- You would be using the same `RayCast2D` for all the instances in the array.

---

### Design

**Turns**

*Before we deal with water, you have a turn system.*

Ideally, anything that needs to run when the turn ends should be notified of the end of turn. I do not have details on how it currently works, but I'm suggesting to change it...

Three options come to mind:

- Have the signal in a [signal bus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68675270/402022). *I used to champion this approach. Drawback: requires to set an Autoload.*
- Have an [static signal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77026952/402022). *I have recently began using this. Drawback: It is a hacky solution.*
- Use node groups. *This is actually easier to get up and running. Drawback: only works with nodes in the scene tree.*

For your case, I'm going to suggest node groups. This is the plan:

- Water and an anything else that needs to run when the turn ends, will add themselves to a node group. *I'm calling it `on_turn`, you can call it whatever you want to.* **Set the group in the scene from the editor, see [Groups](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/scripting/groups.html).**
- We will also declare a method that will be called when the turn ends. *I'll name it `on_hud_end_turn` based on the code you have. Again, it can be anything. Whatever name you pick, stick to it.*

  ```
  func on_hud_end_turn() -> void:
      # CODE HERE
      pass
  ```
- When the turn ends, you will not have a signal, instead you will call that method on the nodes in the node group. *There is no check that the method name matches (you will not get a warning telling you the name you wrote does not match), so make sure it is the same.*

  ```
  get_tree().call_group(&"on_turn", &"on_hud_end_turn")
  ```

---

**Water**

If we have adding itself to the group to get end of turn notifications, all water instances can spread... However, for water to spread, it requires coordination between instances to avoid multiple instances of water can spawn water on the same location.

If water does not check for water:

```
00000    00000    00100
00000    00100    02220
00100 -> 01110 -> 12521 -> …
00000    00100    02220
00000    00000    00100
```

*Each number is how many instances of water are there.*

If water checks for water:

```
00000    00000    00100
00000    00100    02120
00100 -> 01110 -> 11111 -> …
00000    00100    02120
00000    00000    00100
```

*Each number is how many instances of water are there.*

To orchestrate the instances, we will use an `static` `Dictionary`:

- `static` so all the instance share the same one.
- `Dictionary` so we can query it with a key, in this case the key will be the position.
- Although we cannot specify this in the type, the keys of the dictionary will be the positions, and the values will be the water instances.

```
static var _instances:Dictionary = {}
```

Here I'm following the naming convention to use `_` as prefix for members that should not be acceded from outside.

Actually, let us initialize it with an empty `Dictionary`:

```
static var _instances := {}
```

*This variable is still statically typed as `Dictionary`, but now the type is implicit.*

The code will be like this:

```
extends Area2D


const grid_size := Vector2(64, 64)


@onready var _check_up:RayCast2D = $CollisionShape2D/ray_up
@onready var _check_down:RayCast2D = $CollisionShape2D/ray_down
@onready var _check_left:RayCast2D = $CollisionShape2D/ray_left
@onready var _check_right:RayCast2D = $CollisionShape2D/ray_right


static water_scene:PacketScene = load("res://water.tscn")
static var _instances := {}


func on_hud_end_turn():
    var grid_position := Vector2i(
        position.x / grid_size.x,
        position.y / grid_size.y
    )
    if not _check_up.is_colliding():
        _ensure_water_at(grid_position + Vector2i(0, -1))
    if not _check_down.is_colliding():
        _ensure_water_at(grid_position + Vector2i(0, 1))
    if not _check_left.is_colliding():
        _ensure_water_at(grid_position + Vector2i(-1, 0))
    if not _check_right.is_colliding():
        _ensure_water_at(grid_position + Vector2i(1, 0))


func _ensure_water_at(new_grid_position:Vector2i) -> void:
    var instance:Area2D = _instances.get(new_grid_position, null)
    if not is_instance_valid(instance):
        instance = water_scene.instantiate()
        instance.position = Vector2(
            grid_size.x * new_grid_position.x,
            grid_size.y * new_grid_position.y,
        )
        add_sibling(instance)
        _instances[new_grid_position] = instance
```

---

Let us go over the code.

Note: we might add a name to this class, although I have little incentive to do it, it would be like this `class_name Water`.

The script is to be attached to an `Area2D`, I do not have a reason to change that:

```
extends Area2D
```

This is the size of the grid:

```
const grid_size := Vector2(64, 64)
```

We want it to be able to use `Vector2i` as keys for the `Dictionary`, and so avoiding floating point comparisons.

Then we have are the `RayCast2D`, they are the same you had them, except:

- I have added their type explicitly.
- I have changed their name to begin with `_`, following naming convention.

```
@onready var _check_up:RayCast2D = $CollisionShape2D/ray_up
@onready var _check_down:RayCast2D = $CollisionShape2D/ray_down
@onready var _check_left:RayCast2D = $CollisionShape2D/ray_left
@onready var _check_right:RayCast2D = $CollisionShape2D/ray_right
```

These lines should fail if no `Node` is present at the given path, and by specifying the type explicitly, they should also fail if the the `Node` at those paths are not of the correct type... If you get either of those errors, you know you need to fix the scene.

This is the scene we will be instantiating (I have changed it from a `const preload`):

```
static water_scene:PacketScene = load("res://water.tscn")
```

We want it to be able to create new instances.

This is the `Dictionary` with our instances:

```
static var _instances := {}
```

Then we have `on_hud_end_turn`:

```
func on_hud_end_turn():
    var grid_position := Vector2i(
        position.x / grid_size.x,
        position.y / grid_size.y
    )
    if not _check_up.is_colliding():
        _ensure_water_at(grid_position + Vector2i(0, -1))
    if not _check_down.is_colliding():
        _ensure_water_at(grid_position + Vector2i(0, 1))
    if not _check_left.is_colliding():
        _ensure_water_at(grid_position + Vector2i(-1, 0))
    if not _check_right.is_colliding():
        _ensure_water_at(grid_position + Vector2i(1, 0))
```

Notes:

- I remind you to set the group from the editor (so we don't need `_ready`) see [Groups](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/scripting/groups.html).
- This code is to be called via `call_group` instead of the signal you have.
- Here we are calling a new method `_ensure_water_at` with the position were we want to create water.
- Notice that I'm working with `Vector2i`, as mentioned earlier, this is to avoid floating point comparisons.
- Each instance only needs to worry about the neighbor positions.

This will make more sense by looking at `_ensure_water_at`. The method `_ensure_water_at` will check if a position already has water, and if not, it will create it. We will look at it part by part.

Note that `_ensure_water_at` is declared to take a `Vector2i` called `new_grid_position` which is where the new instance should be placed if necesary:

```
func _ensure_water_at(new_grid_position:Vector2i) -> void:
```

First we will get whatever instance is in that position:

```
var instance:Area2D = _instances.get(new_grid_position, null)
```

Here `get` allows us to specify a default value (`null`) which we get in case there is nothing in that position in the `Dictionary`.

Thus `instance` can either be `null` or an instance... However, that instance might be invalid (e.g. it was removed with `queue_free` but not removed from the dictionary). We check both things at once with `is_instance_valid`:

```
    if not is_instance_valid(instance):
```

So now we know that either we got a `null` or an invalid instance, in either case we will create a new instance:

```
        instance = water_scene.instantiate()
```

We need to set its position, which we get by multiplication the `new_grid_position` by the `grid_size`:

```
        instance.position = Vector2(
            grid_size.x * new_grid_position.x,
            grid_size.y * new_grid_position.y,
        )
```

And we need to add it to the scene tree:

```
        add_sibling(instance)
```

I'm using `add_sibling` so the new instance is not a child of the current one.

And, of course, we have to update the `Dictionary`:

```
        _instances[new_grid_position] = instance
```

As final note, I want to point out that I removed `next_turn` from this code. Although I do not know how the turn code works in general, I know that in the old code nothing would have been listening to `next_turn`. With the use of `call_group` you can write code right after. I recommend to use a deferred call to go to the next turn to allow a frame in between.

If I'm not skipping over something, this should work.

---

### Addendum from comments

- You could remove instances from the `Dictionary` in `_exit_tree`. In the version of the code in this answer, you would compute the key form the position as it is done in `on_hud_end_turn` and use it to call `erase` on the `Dictionary`.
- We avoid to `preload` the scene on the script that is attached to the same scene, because that is cyclic dependency between the script and the scene, and Godot is not handling it correctly (at least not at the time of writing).
- Apparently calling `pack` on the scene solved problems for OP (it is not clear to me why). You can create a `PackedScene` then call `pack` on it passing a `Node` to store it (and all its children that has it as `owner`) in the `PackedScene`. Then you could use the `PackedScene` make more instances, or to save it with `ResourceSaver`. I think this is a roundabout way to `duplicate` the `Node`s... So for anybody finding this answer: consider using `duplicate` instead of using an `PackedScene` (this would also work around the cyclic dependency mentioned above).

Comment: This was very Informative and Helpful, My water now spreads, but only the first block.

My water now spreads from the first block to all 4 sides unless theres a collision. but it only calculates the first water. i cant get the created siblings to act. And i know the group on_turn is working as i added that to my character to reset it's move counter at the beginning of the turn and it works well. The water block is noticing the created water and isn't making new instances.

Comment: Some other interesting things I found. I have a level reset button coded as `get_tree().reload_current_scene()`. When I reset the level, The water stops spreading, even if I didn't end the turn previously.

Comment: I also found 2 errors in the debugger. E 0:00:00:0738   _parse_ext_resource: res://water.tscn:10 - Parse Error: [ext_resource] referenced non-existent resource at: res://Water.gd
  <C++ Source>   scene/resources/resource_format_text.cpp:162 @ _parse_ext_resource()
and
E 0:00:00:0739   set_path: Another resource is loaded from path 'res://water.tscn' (possible cyclic resource inclusion).
  <C++ Error>    Method/function failed.
  <C++ Source>   core/io/resource.cpp:75 @ set_path()

Comment: @Hagrid_Ruby I was hoping that wasn't an issue anymore. Anyway, try chaning the preload to this: `static water_scene:PacketScene = load("res://water.tscn")`. I have updated the answer.

Comment: @Hagrid_Ruby The `static var` will persist even changing or reloading scene. However, that suggests the instances are remaining valid. You might add code for the instances to remove themselves from `_instances` when they exit the scene tree (in `_exit_tree`) like this: `_instances.erase(grid_position)`.

Comment: it still didn't work. when i used static it told me i needed a func or variable so i added a var to water_scene. and load would work so i changed it back to preloaded packed scene. after that its still acting the same. also i added `_instances.erase(_grid_position)` to _on_tree_exited and _on_tree_exiting, but neither where able to work. as some other ideas, i tried making the func's static but none where able to. I also added an _on_tree_entered with `water_scene = preload("res://water.tscn")` but nothings really changed

Comment: i added a print comment at the ready func in water `print("i exist at")` `print(_grid_position)`. i only get a response from my first water block. that made me think that packedscenes might not duplicate code. Should we be trying to find a way to put this in main?

Comment: @Hagrid_Ruby I made a typo in `_ensure_water_at`, when adding to the dictionary it should be `grid_position` :  `_instances[grid_position] = instance`. And when erasing it should be `_grid_position`: `_instances.erase(_grid_position)` (although I think you figured that one). The typo is on me. If `_ready` is giving problems, I think I can write it without it too. I'll update the answer.

Comment: @Hagrid_Ruby I have updated the answer. I decided to compute the `grid_position` in `on_hud_end_turn`. I'm hoping using `erase` is not necessary, but if is, you would compute the `grid_position` the same way. I have also renamed `grid_position` to `new_grid_position` in `_ensure_water_at` which should be less prone to the typo I made.

Comment: this almost worked but i finnaly got it to work. in _ready add the line `_water_scene.pack(self)`

Comment: I have added notes from these comments at the end of the answer, so moderators can clean up the comments.