# Is there a way to transfer data between without getting a "Invalid get index 'collision' (on base: 'String')" Error?

Tags: runtime-error, godot

I'm trying to transfer data from one scene to another for a simple modal pop up. I'm using a sensor to sense if the player passes an area (Using a node with a collisionShape2D) and then updating a variable(named Collision) cross nodes to make the "Modal" appear. When I try to update the variable, I get this error "Invalid get index 'collision' (on base: 'String')"

Collision Detector Code

```
extends Node2D

var collision: int = 0 

# Called when the node enters the scene tree for the first time.
func _ready():
    pass 


# Called every frame. 'delta' is the elapsed time since the previous frame.
func _process(_delta):
    pass

func transerData(old, new):
    new.collision = old.collision
    

func _on_area_2d_body_entered(_body):
    $Sprite2D.visible = false
    collision = 1
    transerData("res://Area2d.tscn", "res://Modal.tscn")
```

The Modal Code

```
extends Node2D

var collision: int = 0 

# Called when the node enters the scene tree for the first time.
func _ready():
    $Sprite2D.visible = false # Replace with function body.
    position = Vector2(617, 313)


# Called every frame. 'delta' is the elapsed time since the previous frame.
func _process(_delta):
    if(collision == 1):
        $Sprite2D.visible = true

func transerData(old, new):
    new.collision = old.collision
```

Note: When I hover over the variables it shows the correct values, though the modal also does not set Sprite2D's visibility to true. ???

Answer (score 0):

Read your code. Here:

```
transerData("res://Area2d.tscn", "res://Modal.tscn")
```

You are calling `transerData` passing two `String`s.

So here:

```
func transerData(old, new):
    new.collision = old.collision
```

The parameters `old` and `new` will receive `String`s. *Specifying the types of the arguments might allow Godot to you give early warning of this situation.*

And the error is correct, there isn't a `collision` member in `String`.

*Note: As far as I can tell `transerData` in modal is not being called. Instead the collision detector is calling it own `transerData`, and that's it.*

---

I cannot give you specific advice for how to do this because I do not know how your scene tree is setup or how the scenes are being instantiated.

Thus, the generic advice: If you do not have a reference to the other object (or objects) you need to communicate with, use either: a [Signal Bus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68675270/402022) or [Resource Based Communication](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/199693/10408).